# Isekai or fantasy manga where the protagonist is revived into a boy's body

Tags: story-identification, manga

The main character wakes up in a rock bed from getting revived. I think it was snowing.

From this moment he meets his servant that waited for his reincarnation, the story progresses and she admits him into an academy.

Comment: This question is very terse. You could improve it question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: For example, was he an adult before being revived. Was the manga in colour or black and white? Where and when did you read it? What was this academy (for magic users, warriors, etc or just a school)? Why did he have a servant? How did she revive him? etc etc

Answer (score 7):

You are looking for *[Rettou Me no Tensei Majutsushi ~ Shiitage Rareta Moto Yuusha wa Mirai no Sekai o Yoyuu de Ikinuku](https://myanimelist.net/manga/119997/Rettougan_no_Tensei_Majutsushi__Shiitagerareta_Motoyuusha_wa_Mirai_no_Sekai_wo_Yoyuu_de_Ikinuku)* (or in English *THE REINCARNATION MAGICIAN OF THE INFERIOR EYES)*

> Abel was a genius magician who held immense power in a world where the color of your eyes indicates how powerful you are. However, the strength that came with his amber eyes was so great, even his comrades looked at him with fear and contempt. He, therefore, decided to transfer his soul far into the future, hoping to find a paradise that accepts him. He would soon find out that people’s attitude regarding his eye color did change, but not quite the way he had imagined…

**The main character wakes up in a rock bed from getting revived.**

[image: The rock bed is a coffin]

**I think it was snowing.**

[image: Snowing outside]

As you said, the MC will later go to the academy of magic.

Comment: Yoooooo, thank you very much!!!

Comment: You're welcome @Nomemories, if it's the answer you were looking for, could you mark it as "Accepted"?